# Can't reinstall Office 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I had Office 2010 Professional Plus installed on my Windows 7 (32 bit machine), then I decided to remove it and install the 2013 version.

I went to Programs and Features and removed the software as always, everything went successfully and it asked me to reboot the machine in order to complete the un-installation process, and when I clicked reboot a message suddenly appears telling me that an error occurred during un-installation and the system restarts instantly before I get a chance to see the error message.

After that I tried to re-install Office 2010 but after the installer seems to have finished, it tells me that the installation failed without an explanations ?

I have taken a look at the event viewer and there is some error saying the office protection platform service failed to start, could this have anything to do with the problem?

What could be the cause, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this help? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/how-do-i-remove-all-traces-of-office-2010-from-my/568aeb8a-265d-4ddf-a5fc-e4c8809ebe04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it isn't removing it correctly.

MS has a fixit which should totally remove it for you... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

This also shows you 4 ways to remove it (including control panel and the method above) http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-microsoft-office-2010-suites-HA104027750.aspx

Sadly, there is too much detail to copy into this answer so sorry for a link only answer!

Comment: I tried to install Office 2013 again this morning, and everything went fine without any trouble. Anyway I am giving you the credit as the resources you have listed seemed very helpful. Thank you.